# Make absolutely positioned element [ rendered using React ] snap to edge of parent div on page load?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a two-thumb slider bar component in React, where each thumb snaps to the closest of discrete ticks so a user can visually pick from values along a number line. The problem is, as it stands the thumbs need to have `position: absolute`, but their parent div slots into a regular responsive layout, so the thumbs don't know ahead of time where they're going to need to be on the page - they need to get that information somehow from the parent div itself, on page load. I tried getting my `useRef()` to the parent div and setting the thumbs' positions within a `useEffect(() => {},[])`, but apparently that's not possible. How can I tell a child, the position of its parent, immediately on page load in React?

Comment: it's hard to think of a solution without a minimum reproducible example, or a codesandbox?

Comment: I *should* make a codesandbox for this; once I have something actually working I will make one and edit my answer with the link, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a hacky solution, that works: I pass the child component a the ref to the parent, and have it set its own position state repeatedly every 10ms [ so from here I have the choice I guess between toning it down to something less embarrassingly overblown but jankier-looking or finding an entirely different solution! ]  from within [this useInterval hook](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/), so that when the ref to the parent becomes defined, the child snaps there immediately. There are still other bugs, but here is the working Thumb component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useInterval } from '../utils';

function Thumb(props) {
  const { thumb_key,
          snap_tick,
          bar_ref,
          thumb_ref,
          color,
          n_ticks,
          thumb_on_mouse_down } = props;
  const [pos,set_pos] = useState(0);
  let my_width;
  let bar_start;
  let bar_width;
  useInterval(() => {
    my_width = thumb_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    bar_start = bar_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    bar_width = bar_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    set_pos( ( bar_start + ( snap_tick * bar_width ) / (n_ticks - 1) - Math.floor(my_width / 2) ) );
  },10);
  return (
    <div className="thumb-outer"
      ref={thumb_ref}
      style={{
        height: '20px',
        width: '20px',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        backgroundColor: color,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: pos + 'px',
        cursor: 'grab',
        dataKey: thumb_key,
      }}
      onMouseDown={e => thumb_on_mouse_down(e, thumb_key)}      
    >
    </div>
  )
};

export default Thumb;
```